# Question on AIC and stepAIC

Tags: r, regression, aic

```
AIC(lm(Fertility ~ ., data=swiss))
[1] 326.0716
```

ok, since AIC is calculated as

```
-2*logLik(lm(Fertility ~ ., data=swiss)) + 2*7
```

Why does stepAIC return a smaller AIC?

```
stepAIC(lm(Fertility ~ ., data=swiss))
Start:  AIC=190.69
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read `?AIC`. From the Details section we have:

```
 The log-likelihood and hence the AIC is only defined up to an
 additive constant.  Different constants have conventionally be
 used for different purposes and so ‘extractAIC’ and ‘AIC’ may give
 different values (and do for models of class ‘"lm"’: see the help
 for ‘extractAIC’).
```

So you are seeing the effect of different additive constants, as `stepAIC()` (in the MASS package) is using `extractAIC()` to compute the AIC of the models.